# How to create a formatted localized string?

Tags: iphone, string-formatting

I have a localized string which needs to take a few variables. However, in localization it is important that the order of the variables can change from language to language.

So this is not a good idea:

```
NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"My birthday is at %@ %@ in %@", nil);
```

In some languages some words come before others, while in others it's reverse. I lack of an good example at the moment.

How would I provide NAMED variables in a formatted string? Is there any way to do it without some heavy self-made string replacements? Even some numbered variables like {%@1}, {%@2}, and so on would be sufficient... is there a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is why `NSLocalizedString` takes two parameters.  Use the second parameter to include a comment describing the native language meaning of the variables.  Then, translators can reorder them using the `$` + number construct.  See Apple's [Notes for Localizers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/NotesForLocalizers.html).

However you cannot skip parameters in one language. For example, if you have 3 parameters in English and 4 in French and you don't need the third in English, you cannot format like `%1$@ %2$@ and %4$@`. You can only skip the last one.

Answer (score 10):

Formatted localized string example:

```
NSString *today = [MyHandWatch today];
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Today is %@", @""), today];
```

genstrings will generate this line in your Localizable.strings file:

```
"Today is %@" = "Today is %@";
```

Comment: @user2159978 Did you really just copy the last line? OF COURSE it will return the same string...

Answer (score 3):

I solved this in a project a few weeks back by building my own simple template system with `NSScanner`. The method uses a template system that finds variables with the syntax `${name}`. Variables are supplied to the method through an `NSDictionary`.

```
- (NSString *)localizedStringFromTemplateString:(NSString *)string variables:(NSDictionary *)variables {
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    // Create scanner with the localized string
    NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(string, nil)];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    NSString *output;

    while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        output = NULL;
        // Find ${variable} templates
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"${" intoString:&output]) {
            [result appendString:output];

            // Skip syntax
            [scanner scanString:@"${" intoString:NULL];

            output = NULL;

            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"}" intoString:&output]) {
                id variable = nil;
                // Check for the variable
                if ((variable = [variables objectForKey:output])) {
                    if ([variable isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                        // NSString, append
                        [result appendString:variable];
                    } else if ([variable respondsToSelector:@selector(description)]) {
                        // Not a NSString, but can handle description, append
                        [result appendString:[variable description]];
                    }
                } else {
                    // Not found, localize the template key and append
                    [result appendString:NSLocalizedString(output, nil)];
                }
                // Skip syntax
                [scanner scanString:@"}" intoString:NULL];
            }
        }
    }

    [scanner release];

    return result;
}
```

With a localize file looking like this:

```
"born message"  = "I was born in ${birthYear} on a ${birthWeekDay}. ${byebye}";
"byebye"        = "Cheers!";
```

We can accomplish the following results...

```
NSDictionary *variables = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1986], @"birthYear", @"monday", @"birthWeekDay", nil];
NSString *finalString [self localizedStringFromTemplateString:@"born message" variables:variables];
NSLog(@"%@", finalString); // "I was born in 1986 on a monday. Cheers!"
```

As you can see, I've added some extra functionality too. Firstly, any variables that aren't found (`${byebye}` in my example) will be localized and appended to the results. I did this because i load in HTML-files from my application bundle and run them through the localize method (when doing that, I don't localize the input string when creating the scanner though). Also, I added the ability to send in other things than just `NSString` objects, for some extra flexibility.

This code maybe isn't the best performing or prettiest written, but it does the job without any noticeable performance impacts :)